# text aligning, python

Tags: python, string, text, alignment, character

How could I align the text so that it cuts the first 140 characters of a string, and fills the rest with whitespace?

e.g. `"%140s"%some_text` but the space on the other side.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: `"%-140.140s" % some_text`

Comment: Python is so brilliantly simple...!

Comment: >>> x = "abcd" -- 
>>> "%-2s"%x -- 
'abcd'

Comment: @Constantinius i believe the value needs to be greater than the length of the string

Comment: @Constantinius see the new answer

Comment: @NedBatchelder how would I go about filling the space with something other than " "? Say, dots?

Comment: Note how this took an iteration to get right, the stringformat syntax is a little too cryptic for my taste in complex cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use rjust and ljust for strings. In combination with slicing you get this:

```
>>> "blabla"[:10].ljust(10)
'blabla    '
>>> "blabla12345678901234567890"[:10].ljust(10)
'blabla1234'
>>> 
>>> "blabla"[:10].rjust(10)
'    blabla'
>>> "blabla12345678901234567890"[:10].rjust(10)
'blabla1234'
>>>
```

This is quickly understood by someone reading the code, but the string formatting variant is much more concise.